# VirtualBox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) mac, cant find a solution

Tags: mac, virtualization, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox but get the error  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) on an MacBook Pro 2020 with an M1 chip

I have tried everything uninstalling Virtualbox, enabling SIP in recovery mode, installing the Virtualbox again. Only thing I haven't tried is allowing Oracle in Privacy --> General since I don't see it there.

The following is the exact log I get.

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

Comment: What version of macos and Virtualbox - but basically if an app does not work on a clean install then best to ask their support

Comment: 11.3 macos and virtualbox 6.1

Comment: And you are on an Intel machine? and which version of 6.1 - 6.1.20  is the latest

Comment: Sorry for the broad answer I was distracted didn't even realize I didn't give out enough info.
Mac is MacBook Pro 2020 with an M1 chip and the version is 6.1.20

Comment: Try adding the kext bundles when you start your mac. 
```sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv; sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt; sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp; sudo kextload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualization only works when running the same CPU on the server and the VM.

Currently out of the 3 main VMs only Parallels has a release for the M1 and that can only run ARM based operating system e.g. Linuxes and a pre release Windows. That Windows can run Intel Windows executables. Vmware have announced they are working on a version for ARM. I don't think Oracle have said anything for VirtualBox

There are other emulators that can run Intel executables on the M1. Crossover (and thus I suspect wine) can run Windows Intel binaries. Qemu can emulate and virtualise so can run Intel CPU bases OSs on an ARM machine.

Rosetta2 can run Intel binaries on Apple M1 but not all. Virtual machines need very low level support from the CPU and kernel that Rosetta cannot provide - so that is why you get that error.

Comment: So basically no other way to use virutalbox until they add the support, alright thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 2 years since this has been asked but in case someone comes here for the same solution I needed, this is what I did to fix mine:[image: See logs]

My vm was converted from vmware to ovf and imported to virtualbox. after the the import, it didn't start. In the logs, I saw it was complaining about nvme so from the settings I went to storage tab and removed nvme controller. It was fine after that.
[image]